# Multiselect in DataGridview without the control key (also changing font color of selected item)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to `Multiselect` in `DataGridView` without having to press control key (only by mouse click) and change the fontcolor of all the selected row to red when selected and black when unselected. I'm using vb.net Thank you

---

Found the solution to my problem. Hope this help:

I use the CellClick and RowPrePaint of DataGridView

```
Private Sub dgvUDF_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvUDF.CellClick
        If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
            Me.selectedRowIndexes.Remove(e.RowIndex)
        Else
            Me.selectedRowIndexes.Add(e.RowIndex)
            Me.dgvUDF.CurrentCell = Nothing
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgvUDF_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles dgvUDF.RowPrePaint
        If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
            dgvUDF.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Crimson
        Else
            dgvUDF.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Solved this by myself using:

Comment: Private Sub dgvUDF_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvUDF.CellClick
        If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
            Me.selectedRowIndexes.Remove(e.RowIndex)
        Else
            Me.selectedRowIndexes.Add(e.RowIndex)
            Me.dgvUDF.CurrentCell = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Private Sub dgvUDF_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles dgvUDF.RowPrePaint
        If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
            dgvUDF.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Crimson
        Else
            dgvUDF.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Very happy to read that. Do you mind to write it as an answer and tag the code properly such that any future reader can see it? Also, it would be excellent if you could share your exact conditions (what it is expected to do, constraints, situations you tested, etc.).

Comment: Yes I will write the answers to help others :)

Comment: Thanks. But I meant: write your own answer (and accept it). If you have to wait a bit because of your reputation, just post it after the waiting period completes. Also, please, explain the exact conditions under which you tested it and what is supposed to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

'// This works: I added list to the code.

```
Dim selectedRowIndexes As New List(Of String)

Private Sub dgvUDF_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellClick
    If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
        Me.selectedRowIndexes.Remove(e.RowIndex)
    Else
        Me.selectedRowIndexes.Add(e.RowIndex)
        Me.DataGridView2.CurrentCell = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgvUDF_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.RowPrePaint
    If (Me.selectedRowIndexes.IndexOf(e.RowIndex) > -1) Then
        DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Crimson
    Else
        DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class